# Windows 11 disable WinKey Shortcuts

Tags: hotkeys, windows-11

In Windows 10 you could disable specific Windows key hotkeys by adding the DisabledHotkeys registry key in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` but this doesn't work anymore in Windows 11.
Does anybody know of a way to achieve the same thing in Win 11?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Many of the registry hacks in prior systems are gone in Windows 11. There are still some, but the old ways are going away. Windows 11 is a toy operating system for people who just need to browse for stuff. I am typing this on Windows 11 Pro and I think by January sometime it might become Windows 10 again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

For example, to disable the combination of
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>,
you could use a AutoHotkey script such as the following
(extensible easily to other key-combinations):

```
#x::return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: thanks this worked for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for `winKey + l`

Answer (score 1):

This actually works on Windows 11, you have to use correct registry key though:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`

Comment: This doesn't work or at least doesn't disable Win-W

Comment: Didn't check Win+W, but sure disables Win+S. It seems these "new" hotkeys are handled differently.